# How can I remove this small "right angle" in the bottom right corner of a cell?

Tags: excel, range, excel-2010

I noticed on the bottom right corner of a cell there is a small *right angle*.

My understanding is this small "right angle" means the end of a range for the column.

[image]

I am pretty sure I am not using the correct Excel verbiage.

How can I remove the right angle indicator or enter more data after that last cell so the spreadsheet knows the data is continuing after the last cell in the column with the right angle icon?

Currently when I enter more data or continuing after the last cell with the right angle icon bottom right corner, doing a filter only affects the data on top of the last column or rows above the right angle icon.

Comment: The mark is used to resize the table comprising the data, though resizing automatically occurs when data are added to a cell immediately below or to the right of the table. Before making changes to eliminate the mark, you might want to consider any advantages a table offers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blue mark indicates the range is an Excel *table*. To get rid of the blue mark, right click on that range and then select *Table* and then *Convert to Range*

[image]

Alternatively, click anywhere inside the table and then click *Convert to Range* in the *Table Design* tab.

[image]

For Excel 2010, the ribbon looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Wait does this solve the problem if I enter anything (data) after the cell beneath the cell with the "blue icon" (or the Right angle icon at the right bottom corner)? Currently when anything entered after that cell. After I use Sort, the Sorting function only sorts the data above the blue icon

Comment: If yoy remove the blue icon, it will sort the below data as well... if that is what you are asking?

Comment: Yep! Someone (@bugdrown) left the comment saying that doing so might not be a good idea? So is there a way I can tell Excel hey sort the data also below the blue icon? I dont undestand why Excel uses the blue icon now? Did someone else turn it on? Or can I tell Excel please expand your range to cells below the blue icon? Thank you

Comment: I just replied to your post `I just want to know how can I remove the right angle indicator or enter more data after that last cell` It all depends on what you want to do. Do you need a table there? If not, it is safe to get rid of it. If you need the table then do not get rid of it.